# Order of execution and multiple DML in a single transaction

Tags: apex, trigger, dml, order-of-execution, recursion

I have a trigger that has multiple DML operations in a single transaction. I also only want the transaction to run once.  With the order of execution I need to put some sort of "first run" logic on it.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199485&type=1

The firstRun logic prevents the multiple DML operations from happening in a single transaction. So far, if I have multiple DML in a single transaction I have just been creating workarounds but I didn't know if anyone had a better suggestion on how to handle it. Thanks!

Comment: Is the real goal to run the trigger's functionality exactly once per object processed in the transaction? That's a different (safer, better, more predictable) type of recursion guard.

Answer (score 1):

This is already hinted at [on this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/61613), but to be more direct, you could consider using `Set<Id>` instead:

```
public static Set<Id> cache = new Set<Id>();
public static Boolean firstRun(Set<Id> recordIds) {
    return cache.addAll(recordIds);
}
```

However, keep in mind that partial updates will also cause this problem because the state won't be rolled back. In this case, I'd also recommend undoing firstRun at the end of each trigger:

```
public static void finish(Set<Id> recordIds) {
    cache.removeAll(recordids);
}
```

At that point, your triggers should be designed as follows:

```
if(Util.firstRun(Trigger.new)) {
    // do trigger logic here
    Util.finish(Trigger.new);
}
```

Note that if you're trying to stop the second update from a workflow field update, then you'll want to skip calling the finish method. However, you need to consider which type of recursion you're trying to stop.

Finally, when possible, consider using state-based changes instead of depending on blocking recursive updates. For example, let's say you want to update all contact phone numbers when the account phone number changes, you'd want to query only for contacts that don't already have the updated phone number.